# Stop the GUI even that there is a while(true) loop

Tags: c#

I can't stop my app because I have a while loop, so the gui doesn't let me click the stop button, it looks something like:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   while(true)
    { 
     //some code here
    }
}

//some methods here

private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: And why do you have a `while(true)` loop in the first place?

Comment: What do you have going on in the while loop that never completes?

Comment: Use a `Timer` or `async/await`.

Comment: @Pikoh this is a client app that should always send stuff to the server

Comment: Then use a Timer, or a Backgroundworker, or a Task...a `while(true)` usually is not a a good idea in any case

Comment: Then you need to look into asynchronous programming so that the code can run without blocking the UI, and can be cancelled (usually via a cancellation token).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly if you're running some sort of long running background job then you should not be doing that in the UI thread, because as you state, you cannot then do anything else in the UI thread to stop the loop.  You'll need to defer that work to a secondary thread, or a timer, or something outside of the context of the UI thread.  You can Google many different ways to achieve this.

Secondly, if you need to stop the loop then change the while condition for the loop from `true` to some other monitorable condition, e.g. a variable called `keepRunning`, which you can then set from within the `btnStop_Click` method.  Of course if you adopt my advice in the first point then there may be some other way to stop the `loop` from running, e.g. if it's a timer then you can stop that timer in the appropriate way.

Thirdly, you should wait for the background operation to stop before closing the application.

Comment: I don't think the `btnStop_Click` would fire at all, even when you change the `while(true)` to `while(keepRunning)`

Comment: Well no, that's only part of the answer.  The first part is the most important.  You've clicked on a button that has invoked a method, and that method is still not complete, so the UI thread will not listen for any more input, or do anything else for that matter, until this method is completed.  Code invoked from the UI should be short and snappy, and long operations need to be deferred to something that can complete asynchronously.

Comment: I completely agree. That's why I suggest that the second part shouldn't be part of the answer, as it won't work :)

Comment: Asynchronous execution does not necessarily mean using another thread. The Windows.Forms.Timer for example is executed in the same thread as the UI.

Comment: @Adrian I've updated the post to reflect this - not trying to steal your ideas, just wanting to make the post clearer for future use